# Data Deletion With iCloud Core Data Sync

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, icloud-api

I have a deployed `iCloud`-enabled iOS 8 app which syncs a `Core Data` model. The app deals with evaluating investment properties and records information about the property such as repairs.

I recently received a complaint from a user who entered in 29 repairs for a property only to have them disappear 48 hours later.

There is no mechanism for deleting model objects in my app that doesn’t involve explicit permission from the user. I don’t believe that the user accidentally deleted 29 objects which is why I am suspicious that a faulty `iCloud` sync may have had something to do with this.

The user described that they enter the information on their i-Cloud enabled iPad, but also use their `iCloud`-enabled iPhone to view the synced data. If the sync used the iPhone data to overwrite the iPad data, the objects could be deleted.

Is anyone aware of such an issue with iCloud? Does anyone have other general ideas on what the issue may be?

Comment: Don t know the issue withhout knowing your code... But iCloud sync can be very tricky... I recommend using a great framework that does handle all the complicated stuff for you and is very easy to implement... it s just great and super easy if you want to sync core data via icloud... http://www.ensembles.io

Comment: one more thing when working with that: for me at least, i need to use a custom icloud container to be able to sync across devices, when using default container it s like a backup, syncs only with same device... when deleting app, could restore via icloud... don t know if that s what custom containers are for, but from my testing i needed custom container for syncing across devices...

Comment: You don't even have duplicate detection and deletion?

Comment: I don't have a duplicate detection and deletion system. Should I?